# EF with many to many relation on the same table with another attributes

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, relation

I could' t do a many to many relationship on the same table with ef code first. Is there anyone can help me? 
I have a Category class and a CategoryRelation class too. Categoy class has many Parent Categories and many Child Categories. But i have a extra prop as DisplayId in CategoryRelation. My classes are like following

Category:

```
 public class Category : Base
{
    #region Top Menu
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    public bool ShowOnTopMenu { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public bool ShowOnTopSelling { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    #region Types
    public bool IsPieceType { get; set; }
    public bool IsGildingType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPaperType { get; set; }
    public bool IsSizeType { get; set; }
    public bool IsWeightType { get; set; }
    public bool IsCellophaneType { get; set; }
    public bool IsCuttingType { get; set; }
    public bool IsPrintingType { get; set; }
    #endregion

    public virtual ICollection<CategoryRelation> ChildCategoryList { get; set; }    
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryRelation> ParentCategoryList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> ProductList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<WishList> WishList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Description> DescriptionList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comment> CommentList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Image> ImageList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Template> TemplateList { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<PromotionCode> PromotionCodeList { get; set; }
}
```

CategoryRelation;

```
public class CategoryReletion : Base
    {
        #region Parent Category
        [ForeignKey("ParentCategory")]
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Child Category
        [ForeignKey("ChildCategory")]
        public int ChildId { get; set; }
        public Category ChildCategory { get; set; }
        #endregion
        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

Finally i'm getting this error;

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.CategoryReletion_dbo.Category_ParentId' on table 'CategoryReletion' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do exactly as you are told (I assume that your context is name `MyContext`)

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CategoryReletion> CategoryReletions { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder )
      {
         modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
         modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryReletion>()
            .HasRequired( c => c.ParentId)
            .WithRequiredDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

         modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryReletion>()
            .HasRequired( c => c.ChildId)
            .WithRequiredDependent()
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
      }

}
```

Comment: I added almost what you wrote but there are some differents. When i wrote as here it's functionality was false.I mean when i called the category has child categories. It's ChildCategoryList was empty and they were in ParentCategoryList instead of ChildCategoryList . then i changed it a little and worked correctly

Answer (score 1):

It worked with these codes;

```
       modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryRelation>()
              .HasKey(c => new { c.ParentId, c.ChildId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryRelation>()
              .HasRequired(c => c.ParentCategory)
              .WithMany(c => c.ChildCategoryList)
              .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId)
              .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<CategoryRelation>()
            .HasRequired(c => c.ChildCategory)
            .WithMany(c => c.ParentCategoryList)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.ChildId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

Comment: Good job figuring out. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of the multiple `many to many` relationships.

and you have `cascadeDelete On` which means if you delete a row all the related rows will be deleted imagine how this works on multiple relationships, you may end with a delete order for a deleted row.

So to solve this you need to use FluentApi to turn CascadeDelete off